# Change DefaultMessageBufferSize in SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr

I have a problem with the SignalR library. When I broadcast a lot of data, the SignalR's buffer starts to stack up and allocates as much memory as is available, which ends with application crash due to:

> Out of memory

In .NET Framework, this may be solved by setting the `GlobalHost.Configuration.DefaultMessageBufferSize`, but I can't find the .NET Core setting for it.

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39220093/change-global-settings-config-in-signalr-core) post I managed to configure my `Transport` options:

```
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
{
     routes.MapHub<MonitoringHub>("/MonitoringHub", options => {
        options.TransportMaxBufferSize = 256000;
        options.ApplicationMaxBufferSize = 256000; 
        options.Transports = TransportType.All;
        options.WebSockets.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        options.LongPolling.PollTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
     });
});
```

Moreover, I set up my SignalR options:

```
services.AddSignalR(options => {
    options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
});
```

But how to set the `DefaultMessageBufferSize`?

Comment: Did increasing buffer size fix your out-of-memory issues?  It seems that increasing buffer size would increase memory consumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> DefaultMessageBufferSize isn't a thing in ASP.NET Core SignalR. And there is no equivalent because reconnect isn't supported.

https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/2623

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the `ApplicationMaxBufferSize` and `TransportMaxBufferSize` for the Hub, which is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Comment: Yes, I have these settings, but I need the `GlobalHost.Configuration.DefaultMessageBufferSize` property. In case of connection interruption, it is responsible for the maximum stored messages in memory (per hub per connection). [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/signalr-performance)   Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

DefaultMessageBufferSize isn't a thing in ASP.NET Core SignalR. And there is no equivalent because reconnect isn't supported.