# SignalR configuration in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I have a problem to find how to configure values as `ConnectionTimeout`, `DisconnectionTimeout` in Asp.Net Core with SignalR. In MVC you were using Global.asax file and there configuration were placed like this:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace Wozkowi
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Make connections wait 50s maximum for any response. After
            // 50s are up, trigger a timeout command and make the client reconnect.
            GlobalHost.Configuration.ConnectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
            GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        }
    }
}
```

But in Asp.Net Core `Global.asax` don't exist anymore and as I understand configuration should be placed in `Startup.cs`. But main problem is GlobalHost in Microsoft.AspNetCore.SingalR it's undefined. So how I should add configuration?

Edit:

I'm using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR v.1.0.0-rc1-final. So during `services.AddSignalR()` I can pass object:

```
public class HubOptions
    {
        public HubOptions();

        public TimeSpan? HandshakeTimeout { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan? KeepAliveInterval { get; set; }
        public IList<string> SupportedProtocols { get; set; }
        public bool? EnableDetailedErrors { get; set; }
    }
```

But there still is no option to set DisconnectionTimeout, also during `api.UseSignalR()` this options object can be passed:

```
public class HttpConnectionOptions
    {
        public HttpConnectionOptions();

        public IList<IAuthorizeData> AuthorizationData { get; }
        public TransportType Transports { get; set; }
        public WebSocketOptions WebSockets { get; }
        public LongPollingOptions LongPolling { get; }
        public long TransportMaxBufferSize { get; set; }
        public long ApplicationMaxBufferSize { get; set; }
    }
```

But there is still no desired option even in LongPollingOptions object. I'm missing something?

Comment: In your `Startup.cs` file, when you call `AddSignalR(options => ...)`, you can configure your desired settings.

Comment: Yea, You are right , but do You know where i can set DisconnectionTimeout? Beacause here I don't have this posibility.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Global Settings Config in SignalR Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39220093/change-global-settings-config-in-signalr-core)

Comment: It's answers my question but not totally. There is still lacking of requested configuration options.

Answer (score 0):

In `Startup.cs` look for `ConfigureServices` method, there you need to add 
`services.AddSignalR()`
In `Configure` method configure routes.

you can find more info in below msdn link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/get-started?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio